# Keyrock FIWARE method GET and POST

Tags: fiware

I have keyrock of fiware in my own laptop though docker.

When I do in my browser htp://localhost:8000 , this link redirect to a login website, so it's okay.
When I put htp://localhost:8000/sign_up this link redirect to a register website, so it's okay also.

But then thing is, If I want to do that though GET and POST, how can I do?
I installed Postman in my laptop but, when I put GET http://localhost:8000 everything is okay.
But when I put GET htp://localhost:8000/v3/users if I want list users, doesn't work. 
the last I readed in this page : https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/identity/v3/#users

Could you help me, please?

Thank you very much,

Best Regards.

Comment: What is the error code that postman is showing. It shows in blue at the right top of the response section.

Comment: [enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFXQH.png


This is the problem that Postman is showing.
And if you put GET http://localhost:8000/sign_up it work, you can see next picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/drTor.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [in the link you put in your question](https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/identity/v3/#users):
"A user with no assigned roles has no access to OpenStack resources."

The right port for your request is 5000 (keystone) instead of 8000 (horizon): `http://localhost:5000/v3/users`

So, to do what you want, you have to assign some specific role to the user you are using to access the list of users and, besides, I think you have to pass a valid token (`X-Auth-Token` header) in the request headers.

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Okay, I understand about the port for my request. 
But for example if I put GET http://localhost:5000/v3/users (I want list users) Postman show me a error.
I show you several captures, about the error in the head body, cookies, and headers.
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxB19.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2KbW.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgoU1.png

Before I send the request I have a head called Headers with names "key", "Value", "Descriptiion"   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJ09J.png

Sorry for the inconvenience. And thank you so so much.

Comment: As I said and it can be seen in the error message, you have to pass a valid `X-Auth-Token` in your request. In [this link](https://pt.slideshare.net/daltoncezane/integrating-fiware-orion-keyrock-and-wilma) you have an example of the request with a valid token. I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, but, How can I get a valid token?. Because I readed the paper that you show me, but I don't understand very well..

Comment: I put POST http://localhost:8000/oauth2/tokens but then the paper say "payload" that I don't know what is it. And so, grant_type=password&username=YOUR_USERNAME&password=YOUR_PASSWORD&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET.

But All this information, I don't know, where can I put it. Because when I do the request i have the field "Authorization", "Headers", "Body", and in "Headers" I have the field "key", "value" and "description" but.. I don't understand where

Comment: In this case, I recommend you read a bit related to REST request. How to make a GET/POST request. You have to specify the headers and the body (payload) of the request.

Answer (score 0):

I gave you a reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46100956/7993163) that I think is a more detailed version of the same question. I hope this helps you. Otherwise, we can follow it in that question.

Best regards

Comment: Okay, I think that I understood your answer. Thank you so much. But, I have last question, If I want generate a keystone token, Do I have to put the code that you show me before in the postman? But, where? In the field body?