# Obtain Auth-Token from Keyrock Fiware API

Tags: oauth, fiware

I am running Keyrock Fiware locally on my laptop in docker. I know this is working because I can visit `http://localhost:8000` and `http://localhost:8000/sign_up` through my browser and they respond correctly.

I am having trouble when it comes to creating API calls. I am trying to use Postman, but I am having trouble with obtaining an auth-token, which is required to make some api calls.

Following this [guide](https://pt.slideshare.net/daltoncezane/integrating-fiware-orion-keyrock-and-wilma) I am trying to create a POST request to `http:/localhost:8000/oauth2/tokens`

This by itself doesn't seem to work and I need to add other information like

```
grant_type=password&username=YOUR_USERNAME&password=YOUR_PAS‌​SWORD
&client_id=YOUR‌​_CLIENT_ID&client_se‌​cret=YOUR_CLIENT_SEC‌​RET`
```

I don't know where this information is supposed to go in my Postman request.
I have the field `Authorization`, `Headers`, `Body`, and in `Headers` I have the field `key`, `value` and `description` but, I don't understand which of these is the right one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:**

The IdM Keyrock API requires authentication for most of its endpoints, so you should actually generate a token. How to generate a token is something more complicated that needs some background to be explained.
If you are using the official IdM keyrock GE I totally recommend you to watch this [tutorial](https://edu.fiware.org/course/view.php?id=79) about this component in Fiware Academy. 
It explains among other things how to generate an OAuth2 token using an OAuth2 client and the IdM keyrock.

**Long answer:**

The GE IdM Keyrock consists of two projects: Horizon and Keystone. Both are forks of Openstack projects that you can find in Github. When you consume services to port 8000 you are calling Horizon services which is the frontend component. On the other hand when you consume services to port 5000 you are calling Keystone services which is the backend component. By the way if you are looking for more info about this APIs you could find it here:

- [IdM Keyrock APIs](http://docs.keyrock.apiary.io/)
- [Openstack Keystone API v3](https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/identity/v3/)

The tricky part is that while keystone handles its own internal tokens (keystone tokens), FIWARE uses OAuth2 tokens to integrate with other GEs. For this reason you will find OAuth2 extensions within the keyrock APIs. So, depending on which API you want to consume, what kind of token you will need: Keystone token or OAuth2 token.

For example, if you want to retrieve the existing users using the following service, you will need a Keytone token.

> GET http://localhost:5000/v3/users

Finally, to generate a keystone token you could use the following service of the keystone API:

```
POST http://[keyrock_host]:5000/v3/auth/tokens 
{ "auth": {
    "identity": {
      "methods": ["password"],
      "password": {
        "user": {
          "name": [ADMIN_USER],
          "domain": { "name": "default" },
          "password": [ADMIN_PWD]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you installed Keyrock from Docker Hub image or even from the official source code repository try with "idm" for ADMIN_USER and ADMIN_PWD.

I hope I have been helpful. Good luck with the tesis!

Comment: Okay, I think that I have understood your answer. Thank you so much. But, I have last question, If I want generate a keystone token, Do I have to put the code that you show me before in the postman? But, where? In the field body?

Comment: I create a application in my account Fiware, (http://localhost:8000/auth/login) And then I get the client_ID, and secret_ID, but in the Postman I don't know what do I do. :( Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Yes, you have. The keystone API service for generating keystone tokens requires user credentials that you must sent in the request body.
Take a look to [this](https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/identity/v3/#token-authentication-with-unscoped-authorization)

Comment: Here you have the same request as cURL command:

curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:5001/v3/auth/tokens \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{ "auth": {
    "identity": {
      "methods": ["password"],
      "password": {
        "user": {
          "name": "idm",
          "domain": { "name": "default" },
          "password": "idm"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'

If you are using Postman dont forget the "application/json" in the headers of the request.

Comment: I think, that I have understood you. I show you 3 pictures. Can you see if how I put the information is okay?
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvjQr.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEM4C.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFcmI.png
The thing is, Postman show me a error. Maybe you can see in the third picture that in field cookie postman show me, "csrftoken" maybe this value is the token... I don't know.
Other thing, why the password and name is "idm"

Thank you so so much. Thank you for everything, and sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Could you add a bit more information? How are you running the IdM keyrock on your own machine? Are you using Docker, VMs, any of this? I worked with the official images of the IdM keyrock GE in the past and based on my experience they usually uses "idm" as admin user and password, only for development purposes of course. Take a look to [this](https://www.fiware.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/How-to-install-configure-your-own-Identity-Manager-GE.pdf) step-by-step installation procedure. Maybe it gives you a clue what could be wrong.

Comment: I use keyrock though docker.I know why the name, and password is "idm", it's because in /openstack_dashboard/local/local_settings.py in credential username and password hava value "idm". [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VX0oE.png
And I do this when I run keyrock:
docker run -d --name keyrock4 -p 8000:8000 -p 5000:5000 -t fiware/idm
then:
docker exec -ti ID_container bash
and then I already can use postman.

Comment: I just run a keyrock container from Docker using the same command as you and I notice that the domain name must be "Default" instead "default". Once you change that everything should work as expected. 
Let me know if it works!

Comment: Yes!!! this work!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you so much. And sorry for the inconvenience.